# Deployed angular app to azure app service web app and shows deployed successfully but when run in the browser shows 404 page not found error?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-appservice

it always gives 404 Not found error. logs are as below.

```cs
/home/LogFiles/2023_06_08_lw0sdlwk0005Y6_default_docker.log  (https://smartinventorytestapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_06_08_lw0sdlwk0005Y6_default_docker.log)
2023-06-08T10:38:05.458442645Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/ng' ]
2023-06-08T10:38:05.458447245Z }
2023-06-08T10:38:05.467645994Z
2023-06-08T10:38:05.467666994Z Node.js v18.16.0
2023-06-08T10:38:05.589260559Z npm notice
2023-06-08T10:38:05.590561180Z npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.4 -> 9.7.1
2023-06-08T10:38:05.597526393Z npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.1>
2023-06-08T10:38:05.600323238Z npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.7.1` to update!
2023-06-08T10:38:05.600345538Z npm notice
/home/LogFiles/2023_06_08_lw0sdlwk0005Y6_docker.log  (https://smartinventorytestapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_06_08_lw0sdlwk0005Y6_docker.log)
2023-06-08T11:03:52.503Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:b1dc34abcaac6f00dd945840a5bc6367123b63b56465a5ec20c316eca98e569e
2023-06-08T11:03:52.504Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:18-lts_20230502.1.tuxprod
2023-06-08T11:03:52.564Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2023-06-08T11:03:52.814Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2023-06-08T11:03:52.816Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name smartinventorytestapp_2_3ea52a68 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=smartinventorytestapp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=smartinventorytestapp.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=b11066f3267a7e6498984ab6d3b7a2745eba6596408cd3418260e10128c4799c -e NODE_OPTIONS=--require /agents/nodejs/build/src/Loader.js -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=True appsvc/node:18-lts_20230502.1.tuxprod pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
2023-06-08T11:03:52.816Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2023-06-08T11:04:01.385Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container smartinventorytestapp_2_3ea52a68 for site smartinventorytestapp
2023-06-08T11:04:20.272Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container smartinventorytestapp_2_3ea52a68. Elapsed time = 18.887329 sec
Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---
2023-06-08T11:04:27.567Z INFO  - Container smartinventorytestapp_2_3ea52a68 for site smartinventorytestapp initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests
```

expected to have my application running fine but results in 404 Not Found

Comment: How you are deploying your App to Azure ?

Comment: through vs code azure extension

Comment: I see your log contains docker .Are you deploying a simple angular app or using any dockey container ?

Comment: Simple angular app

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @[Constantine Mora](https://constantino.mx/f/create-and-deploy-an-angular-app-in-azure-web-app-using-vs-code) and @[Satheesh Elumalai](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-an-angular-application-using-visual-studio-code/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20VS%20Code%20and,files%20to%20a%20dist%20folder.) for the clear steps.

I have taken references from both the documents and able to build and run the Angular App to Azure App Service.

As we are deploying the Simple Angular App, Iam deploying to `Azure Windows App Service`.

In `Azure Portal`, Create a new Web App with Runtime Stack NODE.

[image]

- Open the command prompt.Run the `npm install -g @angular/cli` command.

[image]

- Run `ng new ang-app-12June` to create a new app.

[image]

- Run `ng serve --open` to run the app locally.

[image]

- Run `ng build` to get the latest changes.

[image]

In `VSCode`, Install the `Azure App Service` Extension.

[image]

- In `Azure` tab => `Resources`  search for the WebApp which we created in the initial step.

[image]

- Browse the app which we created

[image]

- Do not select the entire folder, select only the `dist` folder.
  [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Edit the Virtual application and add the application name to the physical path. You can find the App name in `package.json` file.

[image]

- Check whether you have the default document available.

[image]

***Output:***

[image]